# Compiling/Launching/Packaging For Android Game Failed

Tags: android, visual-studio, compilation

I am new to this site, seems pretty good, and I had a problem for a while, and came here to see if anyone could help out!

I am currently making an android game in ue4 editor(dev is soon finished), i'll be moving by the begining of march and will have no computer, I have to release this project before then, but I am unable to launch the project on my phone nor build in visual studio since a couple weeks ago.
I have tried every solutions in the threads related to my issue and none were succesfull.

I have 1 plugin installed:
Rama's pluggin for ue4v10

These are the errors that I am getting:

When launching game for android(options: Default, Development, On the fly):

http://pastebin.com/9dTeXs9j

Visual Studio 2015(options: Development):

http://pastebin.com/4giBnfZy

Now, visual studio does say succesfull, but i am unsure if this is normal?

Again I would really appreciate some help, thank you for reading,

Sam.

Comment: Have you installed some updates to Visual Studio or what changes did you make to your code?

Comment: I started fresh with ue4 and visual studio (uninstalled and reinstalled everything)

Comment: And also, it may have been when i tried to add interstitial ads BUT when i saw it didn't work i reversed everything so that shoudln't be the problem either, i'v tried ALL the solutions that i found on the internet, and had no chance to fix this :/ *Thanks for the answer!